# setting env variable programmatically

Tags: java, classpath, environment-variables

I am trying to set the `CLASSPATH` env variable from my Java program using `runtime.exec()`.

```
String classpath = "my.jar";
String[] command1 = { "setenv", "CLASSPATH", classpath };
```

OS is Linux.

What can be wrong with this?

Comment: Is there anything wrong? Do you get an error?  Which?

Comment: the program executes successfully when i set env using command: setenv CLASSPATH my.jar on command line but when i do it inside my program using runtime.exec() and the command listed as command1 the program fails because it is not able to find the jar in the classpath

Comment: Please include all the relevant code and the error message in your question.

Comment: Maybe you should try setting your classpath before you run your program, or specifying the classpath when you compile.  You should also look into using Ant.  I have a feeling you're trying to do something that you don't need to do.  Why exactly do you want to set your classpath from a Java program?

Comment: I have tried setting classpath before i run my program... and that works... but i have to set it using my program...because i have some 97 jars to be set to the classpath and need to automate that for users. so was trying runtime exec() but it dosent solves my problem.

Comment: what do u mean by specifying classpath at compilation? I am using javac -cp <some jars> class.java while compilation but those jars are only required at compile time.... howeven from my java program i am trying to call an ant target...using Project.executemethod()...that is successfull just that it is failing because its not able to find necessary jars in the classpath

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set environment variables in this manner.

When you invoke `runtime.exec()` you create a new process, which gets its own environment space containing a copy of the Java program's environment. The `setenv` runs in *that* environment, but then that process ends and its environment is discarded.

If you want to change the classpath for another Java program that you are going to launch from the current program you can pass a modified environment to `ProcessBuilder`.